# Node.js request data is broken

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to Node.js.

I am getting data from some other servers via Node.js:

```
function get_data(data_url, a, callback) {
    console.log('dataurl = ' + data_url);
    rem_url = url.parse(data_url);

    console.log('hostname = ' + rem_url.hostname);
    console.log('host = ' + rem_url.host);
    console.log('path = ' + rem_url.path);
    options = {
        hostname: rem_url.hostname,
        path: rem_url.path,
        keepAlive: true
    };

    request = http.request(options, function (res) {
        data = '';
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            data = data + chunk;
            sleep(20);
        });

        res.on('end', function () {
            callback(a, data);
        });

        res.on('error', function (err) {
            console.log("Error Occurred: " + err.message);
        });
    });

    request.on('error', function (e) {
        console.log('dataurl = ' + data_url);
        console.log('a = ' + a);
        console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
    });

    request.end();
}
```

I was getting broken data so I inserted a sleep function:

```
res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    data = data + chunk;
    sleep(20);
});
```

I am still wondering if there is a better way? 
Thank you very much!

Note: this is my sleep function:

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
        if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

More details :

- Avarage data lenght 5000~5500 chars from 1 request
- i make 500 requests
- so total data lenght becomes 2700285
- data is base64 encoded
- without sleep function %10 of data is broken
- with sleep(1) broken data decreases to %5
- with sleep(10) broken data decreases to %2
- with sleep(20) broken data decreases to %1
- if i increase sleep time i get better results .

Comment: You are creating a global with `data = '';`. Make it local with `var data = '';`. Same with `var request`,  `var rem_url` and `var options`.

Comment: i already did it. but it is outside of function . here is full code http://pastebin.com/5sgqNJV4

Comment: wat. Sorry, you really need to break that into smaller well-named functions before I can look at that.

Comment: There should be a `on('success', ...)` event?! You could use it instead of `on('data', ...)` and `on('end', ...)`.

Comment: can u explain more . thank yu @marcel

Comment: You may want to look at [sleep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sleep)

Comment: @Krumia The problem is here i do not want to sleep :)

Comment: @margarita What do you have in your *broken data*? BTW, you have to use keyword `var` to define local variables..

Comment: i was wrong. i looked into the doc but did not found a `success` event. So i googled many examples and all i found were nearly the same as your above code. [Here](http://davidwalsh.name/nodejs-http-request) is an example i found. There were only two differences: 1. The data were parsed in the `end`callback: `JSON.parse(data)` and 2. they always used `host`option instead of `hostname`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while reading your codes i noticed that even there same comments, 
you need to set data inside function not outside. 
so it becomes local variable. 
in your function data variable is global.
Because you get better results with sleep() function; javascript needs some time to overwrite global data.that is explaning why you get better results .
just write like this and delete `var data;` from upper lines of js file.

```
var data = '';
res.on('data', function (chunk) {
       data = data + chunk;

});
```